# How to redirect stdout and stderr in desktop entry?

Tags: .desktop, autostart

I put a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=sslocal >log 2>&1
Path=/etc/shadowsocks
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Though sslocal ran as expected, it didn't generate log file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change  your

```
Exec=sslocal > log 2> &1
```

into

```
Exec=bash -c 'sslocal > log 2> &1'
```

The simple reason for that is because `>` is shell operator and `2>&1` uses file descriptors. In order to use shell operator, you need a shell attached.