# Make echo based command clickable

Tags: .desktop, echo

I have this command:

```
echo -en '\033p011' | lp -d EPSON_TM-T20III -o raw
```

It opens cash drawer via epson thermal printer

It works perfect when i execute it in terminal. But i want it as a clicable file/shortcut/app. So I created this file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=opentill
Exec=echo -en '\033p011' | lp -d EPSON_TM-T20III -o raw
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

I made it executable and all, nothing

Doesn't work. So I've tried adding alias of it to `bash.baschrc` as follows:

```
alias opentill='echo -en '\033p011' | lp -d EPSON_TM-T20III -o raw'
```

but even alias for it doesn't work. I'm confused. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect stdout and stderr in desktop entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873799/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-in-desktop-entry)

Comment: The pipe `|` is a shell syntax like redirection. It won't work directly in a `.desktop` file.

Comment: @muru it seems like it should but I changed it to: Exec=bash -c 'echo -en '\033p011' | lp -d EPSON_TM-T20III -o raw'
and it still doesn't open the drawer

Comment: The quoting isn't right there (you can't nest `'` inside another `'`). Just put the command in a shell script and run it instead.

Comment: @muru done indeed faster and easier, I just watned it to be easly launchable but than again i made schellscript launchable by clicking with dconfig and it's all good

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue. First one was what @muru pointed out second was using ' ' instead of " " in alias

and in file I have to not use it at all

So in alias correct
alias opentill="echo -en '\033p011' | lp -d EPSON_TM-T20III -o raw"

and for file
Desktop Entry]
Name=opentill
Exec=bash -c echo -en '\033p011' | lp -d EPSON_TM-T20III -o raw
Terminal=true
Type=Application

Thank you for poinitng me in the right direction